# Passing data between pages using javaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to redirect to another page using javascript, but it will flash all the previous data, and I won't be able to show them on the new page

I have also tried `location.replace(...)` and `location.href`, but they didn't work too.

Here is my code in a fetch function:

```
user = {
    "id" : data['id'],
    "name" : data['name'],
    "lastname" : data['lastname'],
    "email" : data['email']
}
```

As soon as the other page loads, the console flashes, and all variables become `undefined`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use LocalStorage as suggested, or use GET parameters. the main difference in this method, is that even if the user will copy the url to another browser/device the data will remain in the page. that can be an advantage or a disadvantage depends on your needs.

Anyway, this is how to do it:

```js
function serialize(obj) {
  var str = [];
  for (var p in obj)
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
      str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[p]));
    }
  return str.join("&");
}

const user = {
        "id" : data['id'],
        "name" : data['name'],
        "lastname" : data['lastname'],
        "email" : data['email']
       }


window.location.href = `http://SOMEADDRESS?${serialize(user)}`
```

And in the other page:

```js
const url = new URL(window.location.href);
const user = {
        "id" : url.searchParams.get("id"),
        "name" : url.searchParams.get("name"),
        "lastname" : url.searchParams.get("lastname"),
        "email" : url.searchParams.get("email"),
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use localStorage.

```
if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
  // Store
  localStorage.setItem("lastname", "Smith");
  // Retrieve
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("lastname");
} else {
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support Web Storage...";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `localstorage` for passing data from one page to another page.

First, convert `object` into `string`  in the `first.html`:

```
var myJSON = JSON.stringify(obj);
```

Now set localstorage value:

```
localStorage.setItem( 'objectToPass', myJSON );
```

Then on the second.html page, get the item:

```
// Get the variable
var myData = localStorage['objectToPass'];
localStorage.removeItem( 'objectToPass' );
// Clear the localStorage
console.log(myData);
```